# Objective C: Memory management in Block cases

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

I am wondering if I am using blocks as shown in the code below

```
__block Loader *loader = [[Loader alloc]initWithResourcePath:self.resourcePath]; 

[loader setCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *anArray){
    self.answerArray=anArray;
    [self reloadData];

}];

[loader getObjects];
```

My question is with regards to memory management. The analyzer tells me that there is a potential leak (since I did an alloc/init for my loader). How can I stop the leak here? I tried to release the loader at the end but that causes my app to stop functioning. Any advise is appreciated here

Comment: Stop functioning HOW? What's the error you get? Odds are it will help you find the cause of your problem.

Comment: Is there a reason you've declared loader as __block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues:

- there is no reason for `loader` to be declared `__block`;  you aren't re-assigning in the block and, thus, the `__block` is pointless.
- the leak is because you `alloc/init` the loader, but never release it
- do not name methods `getSomething`;  the `get` prefix is reserved for methods that return stuff by reference.  Just call it `objects`.  If it is supposed to trigger the load, then call it `load` or `performLoad`.

If it is asynchronous, then `getObjects` is pointless.   If synchronous, then the completion block is pointless.

If `loader` is to be used synchronously, `release` it at the end of the method.  If it is `asynchronous`, then the completion block could release it.  Note that the use of `__block` in this case is still pointless;  while referring to `loader` in the completion block will create a retain cycle, it will be broken when you explicitly Block_release() the block in your `loader` (because you *must* have done a `Block_copy()` when setting the completion handler if it is to be used asynchronously in the first place).

Comment: I read it on the website for ASIHTTPRequest (http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) that it is important to use the __block qualifier when we declare the request. But am I right to say that the example is relevant because they actually used request in the block?

Comment: Yes, for the reason I described above, only they chose to not release the block when the connection is complete or in error (I.e. Once the block is no longer ever going to be called), thus creating a cycle.  I choose to use patterns where cycles are automatically broken as a part of object lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to use `loader` outside of the function calling your block, it is highly possible that you need to store it in a ivar of your controller (I guess, it is a controller, but I don't know what kind of class owns the code you shows). Once you do that, you can release it in your `dealloc`.

The reasoning is that `loader` should live across several methods and runloop cycles, so a local variable will not do.

Otherwise, just release it at the end of the block, once you have done with it.

If this does not seem right to you, then possibly more code is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions: 1) The completion handler (block) is used by method getObjects. 2) getObjects is asynchronous (it returns to the caller right away though it continues to process).

With these assumptions you can't send release after sending getObjects because getObjects is still using the completion handler.

Try sending a release or autorelease at the end of the completion handler. That should free loader provided reloadData is not also asynchronous.